# Camera app on HTC Sensation keeps crashing

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, camera

I have an HTC Sensation, about two years old. It's running Gingerbread, rooted but not modded or custom-rommed. All of a sudden, the native camera app started crashing - i.e. it opens and immediately closes. I don't know if the hardware camera is damaged, or if it's just the app.

There have been no changes to my phone since it last worked - no new apps, no settings changes, nothing.

Any ideas? Are there any other camera apps out there that I could download to replace the native one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a free sensors diagnostic app, install it and run it in order to see if it's a hardware problem: [Z - Device Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zausan.zdevicetest)

[image]

Comment: Well, I installed that and there's just a red X over the camera icon, so it appears that it's not recognized at all.

Comment: Turned out the camera lens was actually damaged. The app mentioned helped diagnose it (or rather, rule out other problems.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Settings → Apps → Manage Apps*, find your Camera app, and look if you can "Clear Cache" and/or "Clear Data"; maybe something got messed up there.

If that doesn't help, try clearing the apps Dalvik Cache (you are rooted, so you can do that): [ROM Toolbox Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox) and [DroidTweaker (ROOT)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.murga.droidTweaker) are two helpful apps for that. Same background as above: Sometimes something gets messed up here.

A very last resort would be a *factory reset* -- but keep in mind that this would also wipe all your self-installed apps plus data of **all** apps, so have a good backup of all your data available (hint for that: [Titanium Backup ★ root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), which also offers a "Dalvik Cleaner" feature -- but as far as I remember this only removes "orphaned" entries (from apps you uninstalled, and the like).

Comment: I already have titanium backup, so it wouldn't be a huge deal if I needed to do that. I'll try clearing the davlik cache when I get home tonight; don't want my coworkers to hear me cussing if it doesn't work...